# Get selected time from UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone

I have a **UIDatePicker** on my view.

I have set **DatePicker** in time mode.

So user can select only time.

Whatever time is selected by user should be displayed in a textbox..

> I dont know how to display time value - that is set by user through
>   DatePicker - time mode.

please help me..

Answer (score 38):

You'll need to use `NSDateFormatter` to format the `NSDate` returned by your `UIDatePicker`.  Here's some *untested* sample code, assuming you have a UILabel as property "myLabel" and a UIDatePicker as property "myDatePicker":

```
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];

self.myLabel.text = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:self.myDatePicker.date];

[outputFormatter release];
```

You'll want to check the date format patterns on the [Unicode Locale Data Markup Language](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) page.  The string `"h:mm a"` will give you something like `"12:08 PM"` depending on your locale.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.0

```
   // Action where you want to show time picker
          {     
            let datePicker = UIDatePicker()     
             datePicker.datePickerMode = .time

             let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
             dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
             dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
             dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
        }
        // On Action of Datepicker value change or Done Outlet

           {
              let date = self.datePicker.date
              let strTime = safeDate.dateStringWith(strFormat: "hh:mm a")
              print(strTime)
          }
  // Extension of Date
        extension Date {
         func dateStringWith(strFormat: String) -> String {
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
                dateFormatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = strFormat
                return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
            }
        }
```